# Woher kommt die Redewendung »Das gleiche Problem in Grün«?

Tags: etymology, idiom

Die Redewendung »Dasselbe in Grün« oder »Das gleiche Problem in Grün« bedeutet, dass zwei Dinge oder zwei Probleme praktisch übereinstimmen.

Auf der deutschen [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasselbe_in_Gr%C3%BCn) ist zu lesen, dass es bislang keine eindeutige Erklärung gibt, woher diese Redewendung stammt.

Kennt einer von Euch eine eindeutige Erklärung?

Comment: Die erste Erklärung im Wikipedia-Artikel kann man streichen; ich habe eine Verwendung in einem Buch aus dem Jahr 1889 gefunden: http://books.google.com/books?id=pQI1AAAAIAAJ&q=%22dasselbe+in+Grün%22&dq=%22dasselbe+in+Grün%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DEfhUJrqIKek4ATAx4GYCA&redir_esc=y

Comment: @splattne, was auch gleich die zweite Erklärung aus dem Rennen wirft.

Comment: In Wien wird - der ironisierenden Tendenz des dortigen Dialekts folgend, statt "grün" auch regelmäßig "blaßlila" verwendet: ... dasselbe in blaßlila..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wie im bereits im in der Frage verlinkten [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasselbe_in_Gr%C3%BCn) Artikel erwähnt, gibt es drei konkurrierende Erklärungsversuche zur Herkunft der Redensart *dasselbe in Grün*, die soviel bedeutet wie *das ist beinahe dasselbe – das ist im Prinzip nicht anderes*:

1. Im Jahr 1924 wurde mit Produktion eines traditionell grün lackierten Opel **Automobils** ([Laubfrosch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opel_4_PS)) der im Prinzip eine Kopie eines bereits exisiterenden gelb lackierten Modells der Firma Citroën war. So sagte man spöttisch *»Dasselbe in Grün«*.
2. **Bahnfahrkarten** der billigsten 3. Klasse waren früher braun, die der besseren 2. Klasse waren grün. In der Wochenzeitschrift *[Fliegende Blätter](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fliegende_Bl%C3%A4tter)* findet sich im Jahr 1903 eine Zeichnung zu diesem Thema in der ein wohlhabenderer Herr am Fahrkartenschalter eine Fahrkarte nach Frankfurt mit den Worten *»Dasselbe in jrün«* löst, nachdem zuvor ein ärmerer Herr eine Karte dritter Klasse ebenfalls nach Frankfurt gelöst hatte.
3. Nach einer **Anekdote**, die von der Mutter [Schopenhauers](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schopenhauer) erzählt wurde, ging eine Hausangestellte mit einem Muster eines rosa Bändchens zum Kaufmann und verlangte  *»Dieselbe Couleur, aber in Grün«*. Dieser Ausspruch findet sich auch später, z.B. bei [Theodor Fontane](http://books.google.de/books?id=sSNav_HoPp4C&lpg=PA528&ots=Ps-w0-xgoi&dq=%22Dieselbe%20Couleur%20in%20gr%C3%BCn%22%20Fontane&hl=de&pg=PA528#v=onepage&q=%22Dieselbe%20Couleur%20in%20gr%C3%BCn%22%20Fontane&f=false).

Bei [Farbimpulse](http://www.farbimpulse.de/Gruenes-Plagiat.dasselbeingrn.0.html) wurde hierzu ein schöbes Essay veröffentlicht. In ihrer wissenschaftlichen Abhandlung *[Zur Etymologie Lexikalisierter Farbwortverbindungen](http://books.google.de/books?id=4FtclaWzNfkC&lpg=PA130&dq=%22dasselbe%20in%20Gr%C3%BCn%22&pg=PA130#v=onepage&q=%22dasselbe%20in%20Gr%C3%BCn%22&f=false)* schreibt Christiane Wanzeck:

> Die Verbindung *etwas ist dasselbe in Grün* geht auf die Wortverbindung *dieselbe Couleur, aber in Grün* zurück, die nach Röhrig (1994, 2:590) schon um 1800 bei Schopenhauer nachweisbar ist. […] Aufgrund der Beleglage ist es aber nicht entscheidbar, ob die im Beleg genannte Anekdote oder ob ein Ausdruck aus dem Jargon des Kartenspiels ausschlaggebend für die Farbwahl war.

Nachdem also die älteste Referenz deutlich früher als die Karikatur und das grüne Automobil vorliegt, muss man davon ausgehen, dass die Redensart bereits im 19. Jahrhundert gebräuchlich war, möglicherweise wurde sie aber erst mit dem grünen Opel populär.

Zwar habe ich keine weitere Belege für den Gebrauch in der Wendung *dasselbe in Grün* gefunden, aber es könnte durchaus sein, dass neben der Spielkartenfarbe auch noch eine – neben der Farbe – weitere Bedeutung von *grün* in Betracht kommt:

> auf der einen seite wird das adj. in der bedeutung des **frischen**, **jungen**, **neuen** aus dem bereich pflanzlicher objecte in andere dingliche bezirke übertragen, was natürlich zur folge hat, dasz der beisinn grüner farbe schwindet; <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG29938)</sup>

Es ist also denkbar, dass *grün* in der Bedeutung *frisch, neu* viel häufiger als heute benutzt wurde, diese Bedeutung aber nur noch in Wendungen und anderen Wortverbindungen erhalten blieb: *Grünschnabel, Grüner Junge, noch grün hinter den Ohren sein, […]*

Comment: Discussion was moved to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7065/discussion-between-takkat-and-eugene-seidel).

Comment: Bitte, wie spricht man den Konsonantencluster *jr* in »jrün« aus?

Comment: Det musste een Berliner frajen.

Answer (score 2):

Vielen Dank für die Rückmeldung auf der Diskussionsseite des Wikipedia-Artikels, den ich gerade entsprechend ergänzt habe. Dabei bin ich über den Schopenhauer-Text bei Wikisource gestolpert und habe dabei interessanterweise festgestellt, dass sie das Sprichwort am.E. ganz anders auslegt:

"Dieselbe Couleur, aber in Grün, forderte, wie eine bekannte Anekdote erzählt, ein Dienstmädchen einst in einem Laden, und reichte ein Pröbchen rosenrothes Band dem Kaufmanne hin; was das Mädchen eigentlich meinte, war ungefähr das, was ich in Pyrmont gefunden: Alles wie ich es mir gedacht hatte, nur ganz anders: Gott versteht mich, tröste ich mich mit dem ehrlichen Sancho Pansa, wenn man mich hier etwas unbegreiflich finden sollte." 
http://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Jugendleben_und_Wanderbilder:Band_1:Kapitel_33